# Restkit progress information for POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit to interact with my webserver api (GET\POST\etc.). How can I get the progress information of a specific call? (bytesSent \ totalBytes)

Let's take this piece of code for example:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object path:kResourcePath parameters:nil
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {...}
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {...}];
```

I might have a clue using `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`, but I don't know how to create an operation to match the above `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` method.

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete answer:

1. Create an operation: `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:`
2. Set completion blocks: `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:`
3. Set operation progress block: `opertaion.HTTPRequestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)`

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the `RKObjectManager` to create the operation for you using `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:`. Then you can submit the operation with `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:`.

---

The operation offers a method `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` to allow you to continue using your current completion blocks.

Comment: I couldn't see where should I place the success & failure blocks ?